# Sempre preferir xrange acima de range?

Tags: python

O `range` cria uma lista na memória com o número de elementos definidos pelo programador. Já o `xrange` tem mais performance, não sei se em todos os casos, já que não acaba gerando uma lista.

Sempre devo usar `xrange` acima de `range`? Existem casos em que o uso do `range` é mais vantajoso do que o uso do `xrange`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade, em Python 3  nem existe mais o equivalente ao "range" do Python 2 - o "range" agora é o que era o antigo xrange.

Mas no código em Python 2, sim, não há nenhum motivo para se usar o "range" normal. O "range" (de Python 3 - xrange) "parece" uma função, mas é uma classe, até bem simples de se fazer igual. E a eficiência é tão maior que uma lista, que a pergunta que fica é "meu Deus, como é que um dia fizeram o range do Python 2?? "   :-)

No pouquíssimo usado caso em que você vai chamar uma função que precisa realmente de uma lista, você pode converter um objeto range para uma lista fazendo `list(xrange(10))` .

Como criar o seu:  tudo o que um objeto desse precisa é uma forma de (1) recuperar um número dado um índice, (2) precisa interar os números começando em "início", e indo até o "final" de "passo em passo", se for usado num `for`, por exemplo. (3) Também precisa retornar seu próprio comprimento.

Em Python, isso significa que você tem que ter uma classe que implementa (1) `__getitem__`, (2) `__iter__`, (3) `__len__`:

```
class MyRange(object):  # em Python 2 é obrigatório herdar de object
    def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=1):
        if stop is None:
            stop = start
            start = 0
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.start + self.step * index

    def __len__(self):
        return (self.stop - self.start) // self.step

    def __iter__(self):
        v = self.start
        while (v < self.stop) if self.step > 0 else (v > self.stop):
            yield v
            v += self.step
```

Essa classe é funcionalmente igual. Ela não trata alguns corner cases, mas também não verifica se o qualquer dos valores é um inteiro: ou seja, funciona para números decimais também.

Comment: Resumindo, no Python 3, use `range`, no Python 2, `xrange`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss xrange nem existe em python3, não tens alternativa :P range 4ever